# Web audio API : perfect looping how to

Tags: javascript, audio, web

When playing file as a loop, there is still an "audio blank" between end and start.
How can I avoid this ? For getting a continuous sound. thanks

Comment: You can have two `<audio>` elements containing the same source file. When the first finished playing, start the other one and vice versa. Then reverse them as the other plays (it is the reversing time that creates most of the audio blank).

Comment: Hum... should work, thanks. But  no smarter way ? via buffer e.g.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/0xkt1uto/1/

When the first is >98% complete, the second will start.

When the second is >98% complete, the first will start.

When they are over, they will reset to 0, ready for the next play.

---

The Code:

#### HTML

```
<audio id="aud1" controls>
  <source src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4205.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>

<audio id="aud2" controls>
  <source src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4205.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

#### JS & jQuery

```
var aud1 = $('#aud1').get(0);
var aud2 = $('#aud2').get(0);

aud1.play();

$(aud1).on('timeupdate', function(){
    if((this.currentTime/this.duration)*100 > 98){
     aud2.play();
    }
});

$(aud2).on('timeupdate', function(){
   if((this.currentTime/this.duration)*100 > 98){
     aud1.play();
    }
});

$(aud1).on('ended', function(){
    this.currentTime = 0;
});

$(aud2).on('ended', function(){
    this.currentTime = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<audio>` ping pong technique usually works, but sometimes does not work, depending on the speed of the machine, and what the rest of the page does.

Using the Web Audio API is much more robust. Considering you have downloaded your audio file using, for example, and `XMLHttpRequest`, into an `ArrayBuffer` `buf`:

```
var ac = new AudioContext();
ac.decodeAudioData(b).then(function(decoded) {
   var source = new AudioBufferSourceNode(ac, {buffer: decoded,
                                               loop: true});
   source.connect(ac.destination);
   source.start();
   // source.stop(); // to stop;
}).catch(function(e) {
   // error ?
});
```