# how to show a movie after another was finished

Tags: jquery, hide, show, duration

I have 3 short movies and I want to display them one after another to look a unit. How can I do this considering the lenght of each one (about 4,5 sec)

```
$(".1a").hide();
$(".1b").hide();
$(".2a").hide();


var showMovie =  function(){
     $(".1a").show(function (){
        $(".1b").show();
     });
}
 showMovie();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered this in relation to audio - which is very similar. Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31116896/1173155

---

The above loops the audio by using two different audio elements. You can achieve your desired result by playing the next in the loop (eg. pass a count value on next iteration that can be used within the selector).

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look on this

Answer (score 1):

You know the lenght of the movies, right?

If yes, javascript provides a useful function: [setTimeout](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/)

Comment: Thank you for your time.